# CSS Unknown Margin/Padding Showing Up

Tags: css, html, margin, padding

There seems to be an unknown margin or padding that comes in between my header navi ID tags.

Here are the div tags:

```
<div id="container">

     <div id="header">
          <p align="center">HEADER</p>
     </div>

     <div id="navi">
          <p align="center">NAVIGATION</p>
     </div>

</div>
```

The stylesheet that goes with it:

```
#container
{
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #AFAF97;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#header
{
    height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #888888;
}

#navi
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    /*margin-top: -16px;*/
}
```

Here's the screenshot of the unknown margin/padding.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7FMg.jpg

The alternative fix is to put a negative margin-top value. But why and how is it there?

Comment: Its coming from `<p>` tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like I said in the comment its coming from your `<p>` tags. The following should fix it.

You can get rid of it like:

```
#container p {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/zj3HL/)

Comment: That fixed it. But then why is the <p> adding that margin? As you can see, the HEADER, LEFT, and RIGHT doesn't have that <p> margin.

Comment: If you want to remove just the margin between header and navi, you can say `#navi p { margin-top: 0; }`

Comment: @user2902009 If you look closely the header does have a margin from the '<p>' tag, Its a `margin-top`. If you put a border around the container you will see both do have the margin top.

Comment: Now that I know the cause is the <p> tag, is it safe to assume other tags will do the same effect? Such as <i>, <b>, <a>, etc.

Comment: @user2902009 You can try them but I don't think they would, `<p>` tags work differently. Browsers automatically add some space (margin) before and after each `<p>` element.

Comment: Most elements (DIV, B, etc) have by default (in what is called "User Agent") their MARGIN and PADDING set to zero. Yet P has by default MARGINs of 1em on top and bottom (and zero on left and right). This why most web pages have somewhere at the top of their CSS a long line stating "...., P, ... {MARGIN: 0; PADDING: 0}".
If you do this you will eschew this particular problem in the issue on this page.

Comment: To see it, just open Chrome Dev Tools and point a P:

« user agent stylesheet
p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
} »

Answer (score 4):

Always use reset styles

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

> Using a CSS Reset, CSS authors can force every browser to have all its
>   styles reset to null, thus avoiding cross-browser differences as much
>   as possible.

a little more advanced css reset.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

fixed:[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HJSc8/)

Answer (score 1):

get in css

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JZj86/)**

**css**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```